# PHP session error A session had already been started and Undefined variable: _session

Tags: php, session

I want to create from with captcha. If captcha not correct then show same valaue in form.

This is page for add data to session. It can show data from session such as `echo $_session['txtShippingFirstName'];` here.

```
// Use captcha
if(!((md5((isset($_POST['captcha'])?$_POST['captcha']:"")) == $_SESSION['captchaKey']) || (isset($_SESSION['plaincart_customer_id'])))){            

$_session['txtShippingFirstName'] = $_POST['txtShippingFirstName'];
$_session['txtShippingLastName'] = $_POST['txtShippingLastName'];
$_session['txtShippingEmail'] = $_POST['txtShippingEmail'];
$_session['txtShippingAddress1'] = $_POST['txtShippingAddress1'];
$_session['txtShippingAddress2'] = $_POST['txtShippingAddress2'];
$_session['txtShippingPhone'] = $_POST['txtShippingPhone'];
$_session['txtShippingCity'] = $_POST['txtShippingCity'];
$_session['txtShippingState'] = $_POST['txtShippingState'];
$_session['txtShippingPostalCode'] = $_POST['txtShippingPostalCode'];

//setError($_session['txtShippingFirstName']);
setError("CAPTCHA not correct");
header("Location: checkout.php?step=1"); 

}else{
    $includeFile = 'checkoutConfirmation.php';
}
```

This is form page if captcha not correct then return to this page

```
if(isset($_session['txtShippingFirstName'])){
            $customerFirstName = $_session['txtShippingFirstName'];
            $customerLastName = $_session['txtShippingLastName'];
            $customerEmail = $_session['txtShippingEmail'];
            $customerAddress = $_session['txtShippingAddress1'];
            //$_session['txtShippingAddress2']
            $customerPhone = $_session['txtShippingPhone'];
            $customerCity = $_session['txtShippingCity'];
            $customerState = $_session['txtShippingState'];
            $customerPostalCode = $_session['txtShippingPostalCode'];

}

echo $_session['txtShippingFirstName'];
```

It show error Undefined variable: _session on line `echo $_session['txtShippingFirstName'];` . If I add `session_start();` on the top of page it show error `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()` because I add session_start in header file already. How to fix this error ?

Comment: I guess the problem is with lower case = $_SESSION != $_session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP superglobals need to be in uppercase:

```
$_SESSION['txtShippingFirstName']
```

in this case.